# Cython error message: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)

Tags: arrays, numpy, cython

I'm trying to code the least squares estimator in Cython for learning purposes. I got this basic version working:

```
import cython
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import inv
cimport numpy as np


def ols_c(np.ndarray x, np.ndarray y):
  cdef int nrowx = x.shape[0]
  cdef int ncolx = x.shape[1]
  cdef np.ndarray beta = np.zeros([ncolx,1], dtype=float) 
  cdef np.ndarray a1 = np.zeros([ncolx, ncolx], dtype=float)
  cdef np.ndarray a2 = np.zeros([ncolx, nrowx], dtype=float)
  a1 = inv(np.dot(x.T,x))
  a2 = np.dot(a1,x.T)
  beta = np.dot(a2,y)
  return(beta)
```

which is slightly slower than this Numpy version:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import inv

def ols(x,y):
  a1 = inv(np.dot(x.T,x))
  a2 = np.dot(a1,x.T)
  beta = np.dot(a2,y)
  return(beta)
```

I guess this is likely due to inefficient array indexing. Following tutorials on the internet, I modified the basic Cython version like this:

```
import cython
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import inv
cimport numpy as np
DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t


def ols_c(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] x, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] y):
  cdef int nrowx = x.shape[0]
  cdef int ncolx = x.shape[1]
  cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] beta = np.zeros([ncolx,1], dtype=float) 
  cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] a1 = np.zeros([ncolx, ncolx], dtype=float)
  cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] a2 = np.zeros([ncolx, nrowx], dtype=float)
  a1 = inv(np.dot(x.T,x))
  a2 = np.dot(a1,x.T)
  beta = np.dot(a2,y)
  return(beta)
```

But now it doesn't work, I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

What causes this error? I also have some other questions:

What do these 2 lines actually do?

```
DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t
```

Also, if I understand correctly typing this cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] x = np.zeros([ncol, nrow], dtype=float) creates a two-dimensional array x with number of columns equal to ncol and row equal to nrow, that contain floats. But what does [DTYPE_t, ndim=2] actually does? I haven't found any documentation on this.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

EDIT: looks like if I replace DTYPE_t with double and comment these two lines:

```
DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t
```

HOwever, execution is still slow. What can I do to speed things up?

Comment: Which line causes the exception? I see one potential problem - beta is defined as 1-dimensional, but its value is given as 2-dimensional (dimensions of size 1 still count as dimensions)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I defined beta as 1-dimensional because it is a vector, is that wrong? I thought that ndim=1 was for objects that had only one axis, ndim=2 for two-dimensional arrays, ndim=3 for 3-dimensional arrays, etc…

Comment: The value which you assign to beta, np.zeros([ncolx,1]) is actually a 2-dimensional array. Having a second dimension of length one is not the same thing as being a one-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

regarding your speed have a look @ http://simula.no/research/sc/publications/Simula.SC.578/simula_pdf_file :

> Trying to vectorize the code also resulted in very poor performance,
>   for the same reasons. Vectorization uses slicing, and slices are
>   Python objects not implemented in Cython.

DeVectorizing your code will probably speed things up.

Comment: Thank you for you're answer. So when using cython, doing dot products and such is not a god idea?

Answer (score 1):

> What do these 2 lines actually do?

```
DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t
```

---

It assigns the `np.float` (Python-)type to a variable called `DTYPE` and declares a C type definition (*ctypedef*).

Using the `ctypedef` keyword in Cython will make it add the C/C++ `typedef` statement with the given types in the compiled Cython-code.

A `typedef`-fed type equals the type it was defined from, but the compiler will warn you when giving it a value of another type (even it's the type it was defined from).

When using Cython, you should have a little understanding of C or C++.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. However, I don't understand what you mean by «declares a C type definition» and why it's useful.